# Extent Report no generating html

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, extentreports, extent

Hi I am trying to create report through Extent Report; the code gives no error and runs successfully but there is no html report generated. Can anyone please help below is my code -

```
package ca.automation.com;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;

public class ExtentReport {

    WebDriver driver;
    ExtentReports extent;
    ExtentTest test;

    @BeforeTest
    public void startReport(){
        extent = new ExtentReports("C:\\Report.html", true);
    }

    @Test
    public void installapp() {
        test = extent.startTest("installapp");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Anuj\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.46.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/");
        String Title = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertTrue(Title.contains("Trip"));
        extent.endTest(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: exent.flush()  need to be executed in the end for the report to be generated

Answer (score 4):

Append `extent.flush();` at the end of the test method to  write all the test logs to the report file.

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation: http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/#start-end-tests`

I think `extent.flush();` is missing at the end.

Comment: Thanks but it adding extent.flush() didn't helped; no error code ran good but no html created.

Answer (score 2):

the flush() and the close() needs to be called for the extent object to write the changes to the file. Call to close() must be done just before end of the Test as it closes the output stream

Call flush() in @AfterMethod method and close() in @AfterSuite method

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod() {
    extent.flush();
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuiteMethod() {
    extent.close();
}
```

References :- [ExtentReports Examples for Java](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, just copy paste the working code in your project.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.dell.patientregister.mobilewallet.test.PatientRegister_SmokeTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ExtentReport {

    WebDriver driver;
    ExtentReports extent;

    @Test
    public void installapp() {

ExtentReports extent = ExtentReports.get(ExtentReport.class);

        extent.init("myreport.html", true);
         extent.startTest(" Install App");

         System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Anuj\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.46.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
         driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
         driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/");
         String Title = driver.getTitle();
         Assert.assertTrue(Title.contains("Trip"));
         extent.endTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajan; but on copy pasting below code I am receiving error on get method saying "get method is undefined for Extent Reports" I am using extentreports-java-2.41.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.dell.patientregister.mobilewallet.test.PatientRegister_SmokeTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ExtentReport {

WebDriver driver;
ExtentReports extent;
@Test
public void installapp() {

ExtentReports extent = ExtentReports.get(ExtentReport.class);
extent.init("myreport.html", true);
test =  extent.startTest(" Install App");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Anuj\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.46.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
     driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.com/");
     String Title = driver.getTitle();
     Assert.assertTrue(Title.contains("Trip"));
     test.Log(LogStatus.Pass, "Login Successful");
     extent.endTest(test);
     extent.flush();
     extent.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `extent.flush()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if all the configurations are executed.i.e. your @BeforeClass,@AfterClass etc...
Sometimes they are skipped and so the extent.html is not generated.

So add the following tag "alwaysRun=true" with the testng annotation
e.g.@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)

It works :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in testng project even though extent.flush() was added in code. The reason for not generating error was during execution exent.flush() line was not executed due to one of failed assertion. After removing that assertion script was working fine and file got generated as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in generating Extent reports. The following solution worked for me. 
Please add these commands at the end: 
extent.EndTest(test);
extent.Flush();

Make sure you add this version from NuGet Packages - ExtentReports 2.41.0

Answer (score 0):

If it is not working even after adding extent.flush(), Try by adding below dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you are not logging anything in report. If nothing is logged, no report would generate. As given below, try logging something in report. Also as per status of assertion, you can log `PASS`/`FAIL` in extentreport

```
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test Started");
test.log(LogStatus.ERROR, "Test FAILED");
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding bson-xxx.jar solved my same issue. Can try it out.